# Rails Admin - Unsupported field range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-admin

Since Rails 4, it supports Range datatypes(int4range, int8range, daterange etc) with Postgres. I've been taking advantage of this great new feature, but Rails_admin doesn't support it and the app crashes. Is there a solution/fix for this ? I found this open issue on their github, and still got nothing. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1734

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research I realised, defining the new type to Rails Admin initializer solved my problem,

```
class RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::Int8range < RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Base
  RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::register(self)
end
```